# Only unit test observable behavior, not system requirements?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm reading a book on unit testing, below is the code example:

```
public class User {
   private string _name;
   public string Name {
      get => _name;
      set => _name = NormalizeName(value);
   }

   private string NormalizeName(string name) {
      /* Trim name down to 50 characters */
   }
}

public class UserController {
   public void RenameUser(int userId, string newName) {
      User user = GetUserFromDatabase(userId);
      user.Name = newName;
      SaveUserToDatabase(user);
   }
}
```

The author says

> UserController in this example is an application service. Assuming that the external client doesn't have a specific goal of normalizing user names, and all names are normalized solely due to restrictions from the application itself, the NormalizeName method in the User class can't be traced to the client's needs. Therefore, it's an implementation detail and should be made private. Moreover, tests shouldn't check this method directly. They should verify it only as part of the class's observable behavior-the Name property's setter in this example.

So the author means we shouldn't write a test to test `NormalizeName` method, instead, we should write a test to test Name property. But image if the developer didn't write `NormalizeName` method properly and names more than 50 characters are allowed to be input, which will cause an exception thrown later, shouldn't we write a `NormalizeName` method test to guard this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is important to test `NormalizeName`. But you can test it indirectly by testing the property. See this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NameProperty_TrimsLongNames()
{
   // arrange
   User user = new User();
   string name = "very very very long name... and even longer... and still longer";
   string expectedName = "very very very long name... and even longer... an";

   // act
   user.Name = name;

   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(user.Name, expectedName);
}
```

By calling the setter, you also call `NormalizeName`. If this method doesn't work correctly, this test will fail. The fact that the functionality to trim the name is in this method, is an implementation detail. It might also be directly in the setter of the property. Hence you only call the setter in the test, because that is your observable behaviour: If I set the `Name` property to a new value, long names should be truncated. It is not important, if this is done via a private method, an extension method for the string class or somehow else.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you also have a look at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204867/how-to-mock-implementation-details-that-doesnt-lead-to-a-fragile-test

Answer (score 2):

The author is saying that you should test for this scenario by designing an appropriate test , indirectly, through the public User.name property, not with a test that directly calls NormalizeName.